# augmenting a jQuery object with custom properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

In my app, I have a number of jQuery objects which are kept in memory.  That is, they don't get regenerated by another selector search. Also, they are local to the  module.

```
const jQthing = $('#thing');
```

Is there any reason not to add custom properties to this object?

```
jQthing.title = 'All Things';
```

I know I can use the data dictionary but this looks a bit clumsy, especially
when retrieving a method.  Would this be a bad design, or bad style?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this would be a good idea as you'd have some JQuery objects with custom properties and some without.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There may be a more elegant solution to that.

Comment: well, there is this method called.. uhm... `data`, that can store, uhm... data. yeah that might be a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this, but you just need to be careful that the property that you add does not clash with any properties or functions  that the jquery object would have. And that is why I wouldn't recommend that.

Instead, you would probably be better served wrapping the jquery object in an object and then make your own properties off of that. So for example something like below would do what you want, plus avoid any possible collisions.

```
var objectWrapper = {
    jQthing: $('#thing'),
    title: 'All Things'
}
```

So now you can use it like this `objectWrapper.jQthing.fadeIn()` or  `objectWrapper.title`, without any worries.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: ` jQthing.data('someMethod')() `is ugly, but I think one should avoid ad hoc extensions to external objects.  Jon's solution looks right to me but in the end I  refactored my code, as suggested and it became unecessary.